# I work in Python and I am trying to convert a list of strings in a list of callabe functions

Tags: python-3.x, list, callable-object

From something like:

```
strings = ["f1", "f2"]
```

I would like to obtain a list of functions to be called later, like:

```
functions = [f1, f2]
```

`f1` an `f2` are the names of 2 methods defined in a python script (not included in a class)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have something like:

```
def f1(): 
    a =1 
    return a 

def f2(): 
    b = 2
    return b 

l = [f1(), f2()]
```

will return you: [1, 2]

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to call the functions at the moment. I just want to memorize them in a list like in the example : https://pythonexamples.org/python-list-of-functions/

Answer (score 0):

given:

```
def f1(): pass
def f2(): pass
```

you could just look them up in the `globals` dictionary:

```
available = globals()

function_names = ["f1", "f2"]

functions = [available[name] for name in function_names]
```

but note that this is somewhat unsafe, as there's nothing to stop `function_names` referring to functions you're not expecting.